# How to price this option using the Black Scholes model?

Tags: options, black-scholes, pricing

I have a question regarding regular option pricing.

In the standard Black-Scholes model, with interest r and volatility $\sigma$, I have to  eetermine the arbitrage free price at time $t$ of an option which at $T>t$ pays the holder the amount of 100 USD dollar if the stock price is between 50 and 100 USD.

I.e. an option with payoff function:

$$\phi(S) = 100 ~ \text{if} ~ 50<S_T<100 ~ \text{else} ~ 0$$

A thorough walk through in how to calculate this price would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am too lazy to write up a longer answer and I do not know how to write LateX, so here you go

[Pricing formulas for Double Knock Out and Binary
Range Options](http://ciberconta.unizar.es/bolsa/binary.pdf)

Comment: we should really create a B&S realted Q&A ...

Comment: is there one in existence?

Comment: there must be one somewhere. I think I will create a  question asking people to contribute their favourite sources. This question and the answers can be than used as a referrer for the type of question you just answered :)

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: fixed...........

Answer (score 2):

The payoff can be decomposed as
\begin{align*}
\phi(S) &= 100 \, I_{50 \le S_T < 100}\\
&= 100 \, \big(I_{S_T \ge 50} - I_{S_T \geq 100}\big).
\end{align*}
Note that, under the risk-neutral measure $P$,
\begin{align*}
E(I_{S_T \ge K} \mid \mathcal{F}_t) &= P(S_T \ge K \mid \mathcal{F}_t)\\
&= N(d_2),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
d_2 = \frac{\ln \frac{S_t}{K} + \big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big) (T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}.
\end{align*}
The valuation of the above option payoff is now straightforward.